# Why I get no any output in this my javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I received no any output in this my javascript code.The output shows only "Javascript Arrays". Javascript is not working . Any one can find out error here.`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <HTML>
     <head>
        <title>JS TUTORIAL</title>
     </head>
   <body>
<h2>JavaScript Arrays</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    var fruits,text;
    fruits=["Banana","Orange","Apple","Mango"];
    text="<ul>";
    fruits.forEach(myFunction);
    text+="</ul>";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=text;

    function myFunction(value){
        text+="<li>"+value"</li>";
    }
</script>

  </body>
          </html>
```

Comment: `text+="<li>"+value"</li>";` ... missing a `+`?

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools to see this syntax error.  You're missing a `+` where you add a value to your `<li>`.

Comment: Also, I strongly recommend *not* building HTML the way you're doing.  You should find a new tutorial, or if someone is teaching this way... find a new teacher.  By concatenating text (the whole `'<li>' + value '</li>'` part), you're opening yourself up to HTML being injected into that text, causing invalid HTML or even security problems.  You should be setting the `textContent` of these elements instead.  Also, it's usually a poor practice to use IDs for elements.  They clutter up the global scope.

Comment: I made a modern example you can follow:  https://jsfiddle.net/bradisbell/upfayme0/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `+` within your function, but that doesn't explain why you're seeing no output. Perhaps your browser's console is set to hide errors?

**Edit:** By "output", I was referring to console output. Since you've got a syntax error, it actually makes perfect sense why you're not seeing the DOM manipulation you're expecting.